# Unicode working on Windows but not Red Hat Linux : Java

Tags: java, linux, unicode, jboss

In Java, I am generating file having Unicode characters.

When I run my program in Windows (Jboss) and open the file (CSV). It finely displays Unicode characters (Norwegin and Icelandic) in excel.

But when I deploy the same in server inside Red Hat Linux (in Jboss same version), run the program, generate file and download and when I see that in excel then it is distorting all Unicode characters.

Could you please suggest any local Linux setting due to which Unicode is distorting? or where change is required?

```
 FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
 writer.append(new String(data.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"));
 writer.flush();
 writer.close();

 //data is StringBuilder type
```

I have also tried ISO8859_1

*Update 1*

I have checked System Encoding: using System.getProperty("file.encoding") and found that

Windows is Cp1252 and Linux is UTF-8

Update 2

When I print in Linux using :

```
log.info(new String(data.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

it is showing all output perfectly fine but when I put it in FileWriter with extension filename.csv, it is not displaying correctly.

Comment: Are you using a unicode font on your linux system?

Comment: I am just mentioning UTF-8 in program as above. while generating file using Java Coding. Same code working fine in Windows but not in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are translating from bytes

```
data
```

to String

```
data.toString()
```

to Bytes

```
data.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")
```

to String

```
new String(data.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"))
```

to bytes

```
writer.append(new String(data.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"));
```

Try just a single conversion from the input encoding to a String and then write out the String.  So the `data.toString()` needs to know what encoding it is reading.  Does `data` support conversion from different code pages?

```
writer.append(data.toString(codepage));
```

Comment: data is of type String Builder

Comment: If data is `String`, then the problem has already happened.  You want to read in some bytes from the input and then convert it like `String data = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("Cp1252"))`

Comment: It is still distorting characters

Comment: Maybe it is the output which needs to be converted and you need to `OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, Charset cs)`.